# Having two for loop in a single Java Method

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, methods, parameter-passing

I have a method shown in the code below, I have a  hashmap buffer and queue with several list in both. I want to search a particular message to set it true when it is stable; the message could be in either the buffer or queue. is it alright to lump the two for loop within a single method? or is there a better way to put the method to reflect my intention.

so if the message is in the buffer, it is set to true, if not it checks the queue; if not found it returns false

```
public static boolean SetMessageToStable(int event_actor, Message msg) {
        if (mBuffer.get(event_actor) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mBuffer.get(event_actor).size(); i++) { // iterate the list of event actor to find matching message
                if (mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(i).equals(msg)) {
                    mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(i).setMsg_stable(true); // set stable if found
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (DQ.get(event_actor) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < DQ.get(event_actor).size(); i++) {  // search the event actor's DQ if the message has not been found
                if (DQ.get(event_actor).get(i).equals(msg)) {
                    DQ.get(event_actor).get(i).setMsg_stable(true); // set stable if found
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can put as many for loops in a method as you need.

Comment: Since its working code, the question would be better suited for codereview-site.
And there is room for improvements, espacially when both `mBuffer.get(event_actor)` and `DQ.get(event_actor)` return `List<Message>`

Comment: If the first loop returns true then the second loop never happens.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @Ryan, Yes, if the message is found in first loop the second should not happen and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it alright to lump the two for loop within a single method?*

Sure.

*Is there a better way to put the method to reflect my intention?*

The two loops are identical with the exception of the specific map that is being evaluated (DQ vs mBuffer).  You could easily do this:

```java
public static boolean SetMessageToStable(int event_actor, Message msg) {
    return SetMessageToStableInternal(mBuffer, event_actor, msg)
        || SetMessageToStableInternal(DQ, event_actor, msg);
}

private static boolean SetMessageToStableInternal(
        Map<Integer, List<Message>> map,
        int event_actor,
        Message msg
) {
    List<Message> msgList = map.get(event_actor);
    if (msgList != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < msgList.size(); i++) {
            Message m = msgList.get(i);
            if (m.equals(msg)) {
                m.setMsg_stable(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @ John Stone, it made so much sense now. I really appreciate this help

Comment: @ John Stone, if the method return type is not Boolean. return a || b will not be applicable. are my right?